# Distractor Generation for Multiple choice question

Tags: python, machine-learning, text, deep-learning, nlp

I'm currently working on generating distractor for multiple choice questions. Training set consists of question, answer and 3 distractor and I need to predict 3 distractor for test set. I have gone through many research papers regarding this but the problem in my case is unique. Here the problem is the questions and answers are for a comprehension(usually a big passage of text story) but the comprehension based on which is not given nor any supporting text is given for the question. Moreover, the answers and distractor are not a single word but sentences. The research paper I went mostly worked with some kind of support text. Even the SciQ dataset had some supporting text but the problem im working is different

[This](http://www.personal.psu.edu/cul226/files/naacl18_bea_distractor.pdf) research paper was the one which I thought closely went by what I wanted and I'm planning to implement this. Below is an excerpt from the paper which the authors say worked better than NN models.

> We solve DG as the following ranking problem: Problem.
> Given a candidate distractor set D and a MCQ dataset M = {(qi , ai , {di1, ..., dik})} N i=1, where qi is the question stem, ai is the key, Di = {di1...dik} ⊆ D are the distractors associated with qi and ai , find a point-wise ranking function r: (qi , ai , d) → [0, 1] for d ∈ D, such that distractors in Di are ranked higher than those in D − Di.

My questions are a) From what I understood, The above lines says we first create a big list containing all the distractors in the dataset and then we create a pointwise ranking function with respect to all distractors for every question? So if we have n questions and d distractors. We will have a (nxd) matrix where pointwise function values range between o and 1. Also, a question's own distractors should be ranked higher than the rest. Right?

> To learn the ranking function, we investigate two types of models: feature-based models and NNbased models.
>
> Feature-based Models: Given a tuple (q, a, d), a feature-based model first transforms it to a feature vector φ(q, a, d) ∈ R d with the function φ. We design the following features for DG, resulting in a 26-dimension feature vector:

- Emb Sim. Embedding similarity between q and d and the similarity
  between a and d.
- POS Sim. Jaccard similarity between a and d’s POS tags.
- ED. The edit distance between a and d.
- Token Sim. Jaccard similarities between q and d’s tokens, a and d’s tokens, and q and a’s tokens.
- Length. a and d’s character and token lengths and the difference
  of lengths.
- Suffix. The absolute and relative length of a and d’s longest
  common suffix.
- Freq. Average word frequency in a and d.
- Single. Singular/plural consistency of a and d. This
- Wiki Sim.

My questions: Will these feature generation idea applies to both word distractors and sentence distractors? ( As per the paper, they claim it will).

Apart from all of these, I have other simple questions such as should I remove stopwords here?

I'm new to NLP. So any suggestions about which SOTA implementation would work here would be very helpful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is a vast research topic and it is true that generation of a flase answer or distractor in your case is very upholding problem in vast NLP. Since then there are no state-of-the-art method for perfect solution.

But several implementation have been tried, out of which i suggest to use two step method:

1)GENERATING DISTRACTORS USING CONCEPT EMBEDDING SIMILARITY TO PROVIDE INTIAL LIST

2) USE RE-RANKING APPROACH FROM IR(INFORMATION RETRIEVAL) IN ORDER TO IMPROVE THE PREDICTION.

Hope it may help: https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/ebe9/99b7be778a3790af95e981e26c08672d37c2.pdf?_ga=2.11580023.2137318516.1570520867-988658311.1570520867

Comment: Thanks for your answer and sharing that paper. Looks interesting! Will definitely be helpful